# Recursive Update Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a recursive update statement that updates from another table so for ex..

```
    Table1
    (
       IdNumberGeneratedFromAService INT NOT NULL,
       CodeName NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

    Table2 
    (
       Table2Id Auto_Increment,
       Name NVARCHAR(MAX),
       IdNumberThatComesFromTabl1,
       CodeNameForTable1ToMatch
    )
```

the issue is CodeNameForTable1ToMatch is not unique so if Table1 has 2 idnumber for the same code and there are two rows in Table2 with the same CodeName I want to update the rows in table2 in sequence so first row gets the first idnumber and second row gets the second id number.

Also want to do it without cursor....

```
SAMPLE DATA

Table1
idNumber            Code
C145-6678-90        Code1
C145-6678-91        Code1
C145-6678-92        Code1
C145-6678-93        Code1   
C145-6678-94        Code1


Table 2
AutoIncrementIdNumber       Code        IdNumber
1               Code1       {NULL}
2               Code1       {NULL}
3               Code1       {NULL}
4               Code1       {NULL}
5               Code1       {NULL}


C145-6678-90 needs to got 1
C145-6678-91 needs to got 2
C145-6678-92 needs to got 3
C145-6678-93 needs to got 4
C145-6678-94 needs to got 5

in one update statement
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for this?

Comment: Can you cover all the corner cases for us?  What if Table has 3 IDs for a code, but that code only appears twice in Table2?  And is it possible for Table2 to have more rows for a specific code than Table1 does?

Comment: Can you amend your example data so that Table2 has an extra row and tell us desired results for that case?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This isn't possible without a cursor.

Comment: I wouldn't jump to that conclusion.  If Table1 and Table2 always have the same number of occurrences of CodeName, then RowNumber() can be used to to create and additional field to join on, ensuring 1:1 relationship.  But The OP needs to more clearly articulate the exact behavior of the data, and the exact logic he needs depending on that data.

Comment: Table1 and Table2 do not have the same number occurences

Comment: I am sure this will be possible without a cursor. TBH using a cursor wouldn't actually make things any easier anyway. @user589510 - Why have you accepted this assertion so quickly? You haven't even clarified your requirements fully yet which would allow people to submit a non cursor solution.

Comment: @user589510 you can edit your question to add sample data / details of the table.

Comment: Sorry about my last comment, the enter button just submitted it sorry. Here is the data below:::
Table1
idNumber    Code
C145-6678-90  Code1
C145-6678-91  Code1
C145-6678-92  Code1
C145-6678-93  Code1 
C145-6678-94  Code1


Table 2
AutoIncrementIdNumber        Code IdNumber
1   Code1  {NULL}
2   Code1  {NULL}
3  Code1  {NULL}
4  Code1  {NULL}
5           Code1  {NULL}

C145-6678-90 needs to got 1
C145-6678-91 needs to got 2
C145-6678-92 needs to got 3
C145-6678-93 needs to got 4
C145-6678-94 needs to got 5

in one update statement

Answer (score 6):

Using the ROW_NUMBER windowing function on each of the tables, partitioned by the code, you can number each of the rows that have a code in common, then combine the results of that on each query to match rows based on the code and the numbered instance of that code. So the first Code A in Table 1 would matched the first  Code A in table 2, and etc.

Sample code showing this (SQL 2005 or higher):

```
-- Sample code prep
CREATE TABLE #Table1
(
   IdNumberGeneratedFromAService INT NOT NULL,
   CodeName NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

CREATE TABLE #Table2 
(
   Table2Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
   Name NVARCHAR(MAX),
   IdNumberThatComesFromTabl1 INT NULL,
   CodeNameForTable1ToMatch  NVARCHAR(MAX)
);


INSERT INTO #Table1(IdNumberGeneratedFromAService, CodeName)
VALUES(100,'Code A'),(150,'Code A'),(200,'Code B'),(250,'Code A'),(300,'Code C'),(400,'Nonexistent');

INSERT INTO #Table2(Name, IdNumberThatComesFromTabl1, CodeNameForTable1ToMatch)
VALUES('A1-100',0,'Code A'),('A2-150',0,'Code A'),('A3-250',0,'Code A'),('B1-200',0,'Code B'),('C1-300',0,'Code C'),('No Id For Me',0,'Code No Id :(');

-- Sample select statement that shows the row numbers
--SELECT * 
--FROM
--  (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By IT2.CodeNameForTable1ToMatch Order By IT2.Table2Id) as RowNum
--      FROM #Table2 IT2) T2
--  INNER JOIN
--  (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By IT1.CodeName Order By IT1.IdNumberGeneratedFromAService) as RowNum
--      FROM #Table1 IT1) T1
--      ON T1.CodeName = T2.CodeNameForTable1ToMatch AND T1.RowNum = T2.RowNum;

-- Table 2 Before
SELECT * FROM #Table2;

-- Actual update statement
UPDATE #Table2
SET IdNumberThatComesFromTabl1 = T1.IdNumberGeneratedFromAService
FROM #Table2 AT2
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By IT2.CodeNameForTable1ToMatch Order By IT2.IdNumberThatComesFromTabl1) as RowNum
        FROM #Table2 IT2) T2
    ON T2.Table2Id = AT2.Table2Id
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By IT1.CodeName Order By IT1.IdNumberGeneratedFromAService) as RowNum
        FROM #Table1 IT1) T1
        ON T1.CodeName = T2.CodeNameForTable1ToMatch AND T1.RowNum = T2.RowNum;

-- Table 2 after
SELECT * FROM #Table2;

-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE #Table1;
DROP TABLE #Table2;
```

I turned your two sample tables into temp tables and added 3 records for 'Code A', a record for 'Code B', and a record for 'Code C'. The codes in table1 are numbered based on the order of the table 1 ID, the codes in Table 2 are ordered by the auto-incrementing Table 2 id. I also included a record in each table that wouldn't have a match in the other. I tried to make the code's descriptive so it would be easier to see that a correct match has occurred (they order for table 2 is important since it has an auto incrementing id)

The commented out sample select is there to help understand how the select works before I join it into the UPDATE statement.

So we can see before the update Table 2 is all 0's, then we update the values in table 2 where the unique table 2 id matches the unique table 2 id from our nicely numbered and matched join, then we select from table 2 again to see the results.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in posting this, apparently the impossible takes a little longer :)

Comment: I stand corrected, good answer. I've got to say that I have never dealt with more cattiness then I do when dealing with developers :) I didn't think it was possible and thus I gave my answer. Cheers!

Comment: I meant that comment in good faith, the longer I'm in this game the more I try to avoid the word impossible, because someone will inevitably prove me wrong every time I use it :)

Comment: Funny thing is that I pride myself on never saying that word in our game because there is almost always a way. Cheers bud

Comment: We cannot order by IdNumberGeneratedFromAService as this is not always numeric and ordering by can give us nonsequential results... but very good answer I must say this gets by gear churning and I might be able to use this as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

A riff on Tarwn's solution:

```
with cte1 as (
   select code, row_number() over (partition by code order by idNumber) as [rn]
   from table1
), cte2 as (
   select code, row_number() over (partition by code order by AutoIncrementIdNumber) as [rn]
   from table2 
)
update cte2
set idNumber = cte1.idNumber
from cte2
inner join cte1
   on cte2.code = cte1.code
   and cte2.rn = cte1.rn
```

I only present this because people are often amazed that you can update a common table expression.